# Trying to insert two of the same values in SugarCRM PDF Templates

Tags: html, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Ive made a new invoice template with the PDF Templates page. How do I make it as if there were two products selected for the invoice? When I try and add `$aos_products_quotes_name`, it makes two separate tables for two different producst. How can I make it so that two products with their pricing can show up in one table?

Here's the html if you are interested for the template:

```
<table style="height: 110px; width: 1615px;" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Sarah J Bauling</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"> Tel: 011 705 3201</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 Jacana Street </td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Fax: 011 705 3203 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fourways </td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Cel: 083 457 3402 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Johannesburg </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2191</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><strong>Invoice No:     $aos_invoices_number</strong></p>
<hr />
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 58px; width: 1649px;" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>To: $billing_account_name</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Fax: $billing_account_phone_fax</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$billing_account_jjwg_maps_address_c</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <p>e.m: $billing_account_email1</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$billing_account_suburb_c</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Cel: $billing_account_phone_alternate</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 112px; width: 1637px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Date:</p>
            </td>
            <td>$aos_invoices_date_entered</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;">No:</td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;">Description</td>
            <td style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: black; text-align: right;">Balance</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <p>$aos_products_quotes_product_qty</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <p>$aos_products_quotes_name</p>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right; border-top: 1px solid black;">$aos_products_quotes_product_unit_price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <p>SUB TOTAL:</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;"> </td>
            <td style="text-align: right; border-top: 1px solid black;">$aos_invoices_subtotal_amount</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">TOTAL</td>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"> </td>
            <td style="text-align: right; border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">$aos_products_quotes_product_total_price</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p> </p>
<table style="height: 20px; width: 1621px;" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">TOTAL AMOUNT DUE (e&amp;eo)</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">$aos_invoices_total_amt</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Can you share the HTML after rendering?
- Is this HTML from tpl file?

You have to loop through your products array and you need to replicate the

```
<td>
```

tag in that loop.
Current HTML for products seems not correct.